# A matrix is positive semidefinite iff it can be written in the form $X'X$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

> I know the fact that a matrix is positive semidefinite if and only if it can be written in the form $X'X$. But how to prove it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be useful to know how you came across the problem and whether or not you have tried to solve it yourself, and if so what you did and why/where you still need help.

Comment: @Ian:  I take it by $X'$ you mean what is usually written $X^T$, the adjoint or transpose of$X$, i.e., $X^T_{ij} = X_{ji}$, where the $X = [X_{ij}]$?

Comment: [Here you go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Proof_for_positive_semi-definite_matrices), straight from Wikipedia.

Comment: Use the spectral theorem to reduce to the diagonal case.

Answer (score 11):

OK, first off, I am assuming the notation $X'$ our OP Ian uses in his question is in fact, as I asked in my comment, the same as the conventional $X^T$, which I shall deploy throughout.

It is easy to see that a matrix $A$ such $A = X^TX$ is positive definite; we have

$\langle v, Av \rangle = \langle v, X^TXv \rangle = \langle Xv, Xv \rangle \ge 0. \tag{1}$

However, going the other way is much more difficult.  And the reason it is much more difficult is:

**IT IS FALSE** that every positive semi-definite matrix $A$ can be written $A = X^TX$.

However,

**IT IS TRUE** that every *symmetric* positive semi-definite matrix $A$ can be so written.

To see this, suppose $A = A^T$; then $A$ may be diagonalized by some orthogonal matrix $O$:  $O^TAO = \Lambda = \mathrm{diag} (\lambda_1, \lambda_2, . . . , \lambda_n)$, where $n$ is the size of $A$.  Then for any vector $x$, set $y = O^Tx$, so that $Oy = OO^Tx = x$; then

$$
\langle x, Ax \rangle = \langle Oy, AOy \rangle = \langle y, O^TAOy \rangle = \langle y, \Lambda y \rangle, \tag{2}
$$

so that taking $y = (y_1, y_2, . . . , y_n)^T$ yields

$$
\langle x, Ax \rangle = \sum_1^n \lambda_i y_i^2; \tag{3}
$$

this shows we must have all $\lambda_i \ge 0$, hence we can take

$$
\Lambda^{\frac{1}{2}} = \mathrm{diag}\left(\lambda_1^{\frac{1}{2}}, \lambda_2^{\frac{1}{2}},\ldots, \lambda_n^{\frac{1}{2}}\right), \tag{4}
$$

and setting $X = O\Lambda^{\frac{1}{2}} O^T$, we see that

$$
X^TX = O^{TT} \left(\Lambda^{\frac{1}{2}T} O^T O \Lambda^{\frac{1}{2}}\right) O^T = O \Lambda O^T = A, \tag{5}
$$

establishing the desired result.  Note we have exploited the symmetry of $\Lambda^{\frac{1}{2}}$ in performing this calculation.

It should be observed that $A = X^TX$ implies $A$ symmetric: $A^T  = (X^TX)^T = X^TX^{TT} = X^TX = A$; thus a positive semi-definite $A$ would automatically be symmetric if the assertion $A= X^TX$ were true.

To see that $A$ positive semi-definite is not sufficient to force $A = X^TX$, consider the $2 \times 2$ matrix

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix} \lambda & \epsilon \\
 0 & \lambda \end{bmatrix}, \tag{6}
$$

and let $v = (x,y)^T$.  Then

$
\langle v, Av \rangle = (x, y)
\begin{bmatrix} \lambda & \epsilon \\
0 & \lambda \end{bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \lambda (x^2 + y^2) + \epsilon xy \tag{7}
$

I claim that, at least for $\lambda > 0$ and $\vert \epsilon \vert \le \lambda$,

$\lambda (x^2 + y^2) + \epsilon xy \ge 0 \tag{8}$

for all $(x, y)^T$.  To see this, note that we can, without loss of generality, take $\vert x \vert \le \vert y \vert$, since the quadratic form $\lambda (x^2 + y^2) + \epsilon x y$ is symmetric in $x$ and $y$.  Then we have

$\vert \epsilon x y \vert  = \vert \epsilon  \vert \vert x \vert \vert y \vert  \le  \lambda \vert y \vert ^2 = \lambda y^2, \tag{9}$

or

$- \lambda y^2 \le \epsilon x y  \le \lambda y^2, \tag {10}$

whence

$0 \le \lambda y ^2 + \epsilon x y \le \lambda (x^2 + y^2) + \epsilon x y, \tag {11}$

showing that $A$ is positive semi-definite.  But there is no similarity transformation which diagonalizes $A$; indeed, if for some nonsingular $W$, $WAW^{-1}$ *were* diagonal, we would have to have $WAW^{-1} = \lambda I$,
since the characteristic polynomial of a matrix is a similarity invariant.  But then we would have $W(A - \lambda I)W^{-1} = 0$; but this is impossible since $A - \lambda I = \epsilon N$,  where $N = [\delta_{i, i + 1}]$ is a non-vanishing, albeit nilpotent, matrix; it cannot be "similaritized" into vanishing.

In closing:  certain generaizations may be possible:  if $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix of the form

$A = \lambda I + \epsilon N, \tag{12}$

then  $A$ is positive semi-definite provided $\vert \epsilon \vert \le \frac{\lambda}{n - 1}$ for $\lambda > 0$; furthermore $A$ can't be diagonalized; the arguments are essentially the same as those given above.

Sorry about all the false starts, false alarms, and repetitive editing.

Hope this helps.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Let me provide a rather elementary method for real symmetric matrix $A$ (since OP didn't mention in which field the entries are):

First, suppose that a real symmetric matrix $A$ is positive semidefinite, then we can find an **invertible** matrix $P$, such that $$P^{T}AP=\operatorname{diag}\{\underbrace{1,1,...,1}_r,\underbrace{0,0,...,0}_{n-r}\}.$$
Multiply $(P^{T})^{-1}=(P^{-1})^T$ and $P^{-1}$ on the left and right side of the RHS, we have
$$ A=(P^{-1})^{T}\operatorname{diag}\{\underbrace{1,1,...,1}_r,\underbrace{0,0,...,0}_{n-r}\}P^{-1} .$$
If we force the last $(n-r)$ rows of $P^{-1}$ to be zero, and denote the new matrix by $X$, then
$$ A=X^{T}X $$ and we are done.

To show the converse, it suffices to note that if $ A=X^{T}X $, then for every $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\ne 0$ we have $$xAx^{T}=xX^{T}Xx^{T}=(xX^{T})(xX^{T})^{T}\ge 0.$$