# A basic question on diagonalizability

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How to prove that the following linear map :

$T : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ defined by $$T(e_1)=e_2$$
$$T(e_2)=0$$

can't be diagonalized with respect to any basis. Here $e_i$s are standard basis.

Comment: What's the characteristic polynomial for $T$? That's usually a good place to start.

Comment: If it were diagonalizable, it would be $T=0$. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transformation is diagonalizable iff its eigenvectors form a basis of the vector space.  In this case, $T$'s only eigenvectors are the multiples of $e_2$.  Since these do not form a basis of $\mathbb R^2$, $T$ is not diagonalizable.

Answer (score 2):

Any map is diagonalizable if and only if it has the same number of linearly independent eigenvectors as the dimension of the space.

In your case, there is only one eigenvalue i.e. $0$ and the corresponding eigenspace is one dimensional. Hence, it does not have "enough" number of linearly independent eigenvectors and therefore cannot be diagonalized.

To see why there is no other eigenvalue, let

$$ T(ae_{1} + be_{2}) = \lambda(ae_{1} + be_{2})$$

which implies

$$ ae_{2} = \lambda a e_{1} + \lambda b e_{2}$$

which immediately gives $\lambda = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

One explanation by Yours Truly can be found in my answer to this question:

[Proof of a matrix is positive semidefinite iff it can be written in the form $X'X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482688/proof-of-a-matrix-is-positive-semidefinite-iff-it-can-be-written-in-the-form-x)

Look between equations (10) and (12)!