# Any positive semidefinite matrix can be written as $AA^{\ast}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that for any matrix $A$, $AA^{\ast}$ is positive semidefinite (where $A^\ast$ is $\overline{A}^T$). Please help me show the following statement

> Any positive semidefinite can be written as $AA^{\ast}$.

Comment: Hint: Write $B = U DU^*$, where $D$ is diagonal with nonnegative entries and $U$ unitary.

Comment: and then $B=U(‎‎\dfrac{D+D^{\ast}}{2}‎)U^{\ast}$? yes? is this true?

Answer (score 5):

If $A \ge 0$ and $A = A^*$, then $A$ is unitarily diagonalizable and all eigenvalues are real and non-negative. That is, for some unitary $U$, we have $U^*AU = \Lambda$, where $\Lambda = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$, and $\lambda_k \ge 0$.

If we let $\Lambda^{\frac{1}{2}} = \operatorname{diag}(\sqrt{\lambda_1},...,\sqrt{\lambda_n})$, then we note that $(\Lambda^{\frac{1}{2}})^* = \Lambda^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and see that
$A = U \Lambda U^* = U \Lambda^{\frac{1}{2}} \Lambda^{\frac{1}{2}} U^*= U \Lambda^{\frac{1}{2}} (\Lambda^{\frac{1}{2}})^* U^* = U \Lambda^{\frac{1}{2}} ( U \Lambda^{\frac{1}{2}})^*$, as desired.

**Aside**:
The Hermitian assumption is necessary. The matrix $A= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ satisfies $\langle x, Ax \rangle \ge 0$ for all $x$, but cannot be written as $B B^*$ for any matrix $B$. (This follows since $B B^*$ is self-adjoint, but $A$ is not.)

Comment: but we dont have this assumption that $A=A^{\ast}$!!!

Comment: @copper.hat et al:  not to put too fine a point on it, but the question as posted does not hypothesize $A$ to be self-adjoint (Hermitian).  My answer below fleshes out some details.  Best, RKL.

Comment: @RobertLewis: I'm not sure what fine point you are referring to. That is why I have it as an assumption.

Comment: @math: Some authors include 'self-adjointness' in the the definition.

Comment: @math so you want to express as a self-adjoint matrix a matrix which supposedly not self-adjoint? Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prove that any positive semidefinite matrix may be written $AA^*$ because it is not true.  A complete explication for the real case is found in my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482688/proof-of-a-matrix-is-positive-semidefinite-iff-it-can-be-written-in-the-form-x); the argument in the complex case involves only the usual modifications:  transpose is replaced by Hermitian adjoint, orthogonal by unitary, and so forth.

Hope this helps!  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: but have you any counter example that this statement is false???

Comment: @math: I have a 'counterexample' below.

Comment: @math: a real counterexample similar to copper.hat's is given in my linked post.

Comment: @copper.hat thank you very much

Comment: Lot of Bay Area folks here!

Comment: @copper.hat:  you in the Bay Area too?  Checked your profile:  Albany, guess you are!

Comment: Enjoying the wonderful sounds of BART as we write...

Comment: To copper.hat:  you on the train NOW? or just live near the tracks?  I must say I was mos' def glad to hear those trains rumble again!

Comment: Just near! ${}{}$